# How sbt run internally works to run a play service

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am looking to understand how sbt run command internally works to start play server. Is there a way where I can keep some sort of debug points to know how the server is getting started? which can help me understand how it internally works.

I know that we write up a Module.Scala and the contexts will be initialised from here, is there a way to find me out what exactly is happening here?

Comment: You could attach a debugger.

Comment: Are you looking to understand how a Play server is started generally or specifically how the `sbt run` command works? For the latter, you can have a look to the play SBT plugin [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/main/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/sbt/PlayRun.scala) as an entrypoint. For the former, it's "just" a main class, you can look at the code [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/main/transport/server/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ProdServerStart.scala) as an entrypoint as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug.

I'm using IntelliJ IDE and there is an option to edit run configurations in the IntelliJ menu, clicked on it and did the set of sbt run command I was triggering in local.

Provide the url - hostname and port to start running application at that point

Set the options as in sbt run along with existing options, if any

Change the module to right module( where Module.scala is present)

Click Apply(to save changes) and then click on ok.

Start this build configuration in debug mode. Within the application, Module.scala executes first, so we can keep debug points starting from here to understand the flow.

Happy Exploring :) Thanks.